# How to configure Axon 4 context in Vert.x

Tags: java, vert.x, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I'm using Axon for implementation of CQRS/Event sourcing in my Vert.X microservice.
In the bootstrap of my Verticle I have a createInfra methid for creation of my Axon context.
When I try to get a ressource from ny projection I have no result and the request executed without end. When I check the QueryGateway, in the SimpleGatewayBus I have no subscription.

If someone can help me for fix my Axon configuration ? And I have a trouble with MongoDB Eventstore configuration.

Verticle

```
package com.omb..restadapter;

import com.omb..domain.commands.MyAggregate;
import com.omb..infra.repositories.MongoAggregateProjector;
import com.omb..infra.repositories.MongoAggregateRepository;
import com.omb..restadapter.handler.MyCommandHandler;
import com.omb..restadapter.handler.MyQueryHandler;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.PubSecKeyOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.jwt.JWTAuth;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.jwt.JWTAuthOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.healthchecks.HealthCheckHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.healthchecks.Status;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.BodyHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.CorsHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.JWTAuthHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;
import org.axonframework.config.AggregateConfigurer;
import org.axonframework.config.Configuration;
import org.axonframework.config.Configurer;
import org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer;
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingRepository;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.eventsourcing.tokenstore.MongoTokenStore;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private MyCommandHandler MyCommandHandler;
    private MyQueryHandler MyQueryHandler;
    private static final String APP_JSON = "application/json";
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyVerticle.class.getName());

    public static final String RESOURCE_NAME = "My";

    /**
     * Convenience method so you can run it in your IDE
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner.runExample(MyVerticle.class);
    }

    /**
     * Start the verticle
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {

        Future<Void> steps = createInfra().compose(t -> createRouter());

        steps.onComplete(ar -> {
            if(ar.succeeded()) {
                startFuture.complete();
            } else {
                log.throwing(MyVerticle.class.getName(), "start", ar.cause());
                startFuture.fail(ar.cause());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Stop the Verticle
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Create the server
     *
     * @return
     */
    private Future<Void> createRouter() {
        return Future.future(promise -> {
            final Router router = Router.router(vertx);

            final JWTAuth authProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, getJWTAuthOptions());

            // allow route for CORS
            router.route()
                    .handler(CorsHandler.create(".*.").allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.GET)
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.POST)
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.DELETE)
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.PUT).allowCredentials(true)
                            .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Method").allowedHeader("Authorization")
                            .allowedHeader("idPartner").allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                            .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials").allowedHeader("Content-Type"));

            router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create()).failureHandler(new FailureHandler());

            router.get("/my-reources").produces(APP_JSON).handler(MyQueryHandler::getAllResource);
            router.post("/my-resources").consumes(APP_JSON).produces(APP_JSON).handler(MyCommandHandler::createMy);
            

            // Healthcheck
            router.get("/health*").handler(HealthCheckHandler.create(vertx).register("health", res -> res.complete(Status.OK())));

            // Swagger
            router.route("/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());

            vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8083);
            promise.complete();
        });
    }

    private Future<Void> createInfra() {
        return Future.future(promise -> {

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(config().getString(ConfigResource.CONFIG_MONGODB_URL));
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("resource");
            MongoAggregateRepository repository = new MongoMyRepository(database);
            MongoAggregateProjector MyProjector = new MongoAggregateProjector(repository);

            Configuration configuration = DefaultConfigurer
                    .defaultConfiguration()
                    .configureAggregate(MyAggregate.class)
                    .eventProcessing(conf -> conf.registerTokenStore(config -> MongoTokenStore.builder().build()))
                    .registerEventHandler(conf -> MyProjector)
                    .registerQueryHandler(conf -> MyProjector)
                    .buildConfiguration();

            // Write
            MyCommandHandler = new MyCommandHandler(configuration.commandGateway());

            // Read
            MyQueryHandler = new MyQueryHandler(configuration.queryGateway());

            promise.complete();
        });
    }
}
```

Projector

```
package com.omb..infra.repositories;

import com.omb..domain.events.AggregateCreatedEvent;
import com.omb..domain.events.AggregateUpdatedEvent;
import com.omb..domain.queries.FindAggregateQuery;
import com.omb..domain.queries.FindAggregatesQuery;
import com.omb..domain.queries.IAggregateProjector;
import com.omb..domain.queries.AggregateView;
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.EventHandler;
import org.axonframework.queryhandling.QueryHandler;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MongoAggregateProjector implements IAggregateProjector {

    private MongoAggregateRepository repository;

    public MongoAggregateProjector(MongoAggregateRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    @EventHandler
    public void on(AggregateCreatedEvent event) {
        AggregateDocument AggregateDocument = new AggregateDocument(event.getId(), event.getName());
        repository.addAggregate(AggregateDocument);
    }

    @Override
    @EventHandler
    public void on(AggregateUpdatedEvent event) {
        AggregateDocument AggregateDocument = new AggregateDocument(event.getId(), event.getName());
        repository.updateAggregate(AggregateDocument);
    }

    @Override
    @QueryHandler
    public Optional<AggregateView> handle(FindAggregateQuery query) {
        return repository.getAggregate(query.getAggregateId()).map(AggregateDocument::toView);
    }

    @Override
    @QueryHandler
    public List<AggregateView> handle(FindAggregatesQuery query) {
        return repository.getAggregates().stream().map(AggregateDocument::toView).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Aggregate

```
package com.omb..domain.commands;

import com.omb..domain.events.AggregateCreatedEvent;
import com.omb..domain.events.AggregateUpdatedEvent;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingHandler;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateIdentifier;

import static org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateLifecycle.apply;

public class MyAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String myAggregateId;
    private String name;

    public Aggregate() {}

    @CommandHandler
    public Aggregate(CreateAggregateCommand command) {
        apply(new AggregateCreatedEvent(command.getId(), command.getName()));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(UpdateAggregateCommand command) {
        apply(new AggregateUpdatedEvent(command.getId(), command.getName()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(AggregateCreatedEvent event) {
        AggregateId = event.getId();
        name = event.getName();
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(AggregateUpdatedEvent event) {
        AggregateId = event.getId();
        name = event.getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 problems in the configuration:

1. You just "build" the configuration, but don't start it. After `buildConfiguration()`, make sure to call 'start()' on the returned Configuration instance. Alternatively, directly call `start()` on the Configurer. It returns a started configuration instance.

   That should resolve the registrations not coming through. But it will probably trigger an exception related to the next issue....
2. Your MongoTokenStore configuration is incomplete. The TokenStore needs at least a serializer and a `MongoTemplate` instance. The latter tells the Axon which collections you want to certain types of information in. In your case, only the `TrackingTokenCollection` would be relant.

   ```java
   config -> MongoTokenStore.builder()
                            .mongoTemplate(
                                DefaultMongoTemplate.builder()
                                                    // optionally choose collection names here
                                                    .mongoDatabase(mongoClient)
                                                    .build())
                            .serializer(Configuration::serializer)
                            .build()
   ```

I recommend checking the options in the builders to ensure you don't need to configure any other things that are specific to your environment. The default work in generic cases, but may not be valid for you.